# Angular HttpInterceptor htting 400 bad request when adding authorization header

Tags: angular, rest, angular-http-interceptors, bad-request

I keep hitting HTTP error - 400 (bad request) when trying to add authorization header with HTTPInterceptor

I tested with Postman, and it works
[image: Tested with Postman]

Here is the code:

**Interceptor**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterceptrorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
    'x-api-key': 'a404823a-55b8-419e-bcbf-8ebb9ff7bae3',
    }
  });
  return next.handle(req);
 }
```

}

**TestService**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  test() {
    return this.http.get('http://motorway:8000/wluntest/test');
  }
}
```

**app.module**

```
providers: [
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: InterceptrorService,
  multi: true
}
```

],

**app.component**

```
constructor(private test: TestService) {
  this.test.test().subscribe(value => console.log(value));
}
```

[image: 400 - bad request]

The api is mock api constructed with Gravitee

**Angular version**

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.4
Node: 10.13.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
```

[image: Http Interceptor log]

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happened because of CROS in backend (Gravitee)
`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` needed to configured to allow custom headers.

More info on : https://docs.gravitee.io/apim_publisherguide_configuring_cors.html

Answer (score 1):

try to add headers like this.

```
req = req.clone({headers:req.headers.set('x-api-key','a404823a-55b8-419e-bcbf-8ebb9ff7bae3')});
```

Comment: I log the header, the header is added, however the error 400 bad request still persist. Not sure why

Comment: btw I refer to this tutorial: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the response body is not a JSON object as the http-client wraps everything into Object(by default). So what you could do:

- Change the response body into returning `{ msg: 'hello' }` and in the callback pick it up by `console.log(value.msg)`
- Or handle the fact its just plain text by adding `{responseType: 'text'}`, in your example:

  ```
  test() {
    return this.http.get('http://motorway:8000/wluntest/test', {responseType: 'text'});
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks Lucho, it still returning 400 - bad request though.

Comment: btw I refer to this tutorial: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Comment: What change did you do?what's the result with postman, did the body change?

Comment: I missed your attachment on the network log on the request, your last issue seems to be the type of request, which seems strange enough changing to request method `OPTIONS`. Can you inside your `interceptor add console.log(req)` just before `return next.handle(req);` and update your question with the output.

Comment: I added `responseType` and changed the return data to return json, it still return 400 bad request. In the postman, everything is working find, returning `{"message":"hello"}`

Comment: I added the network log as your request to the question.

Comment: Ok that's great, but then you don't need `responseType` as the default is JSON.

Comment: It still doesnt work. Funny thing is when i `setParams` it will work, the final url will become like this http://motorway:8000/wluntest/test?api-key=a404823a-55b8-419e-bcbf-8ebb9ff7bae3

Comment: I beleive it's because request method changed to GET, can you check in the devTool network tab to confirm it?

Comment: The api is able to handle both `POST` and `GET` request. However in the devTool, i noticed that the  request method becomes options, `Request Method: OPTIONS`

Comment: Yes I already commented that, but did it change to GET when you put serParam?.....

Comment: Yes indeed, it changed to `GET` when i `setParams`